# HTML/Javascript code will not validate a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to validate the textboxes in a form but when the submit button is clicked and all boxes are empty all the code does is move on like it is all correctly filled out even when it isn't. This is the code I am using to validate the textboxes

```
function validateAndEmail(){        
    if(document.channelForm.chanName.value == “”) {
        alert(“Please provide your channel name.”);
        Return false;
    }
    else if(document.channelForm.chanURL.value == “”) {
        alert(“Please provide your channel URL.”);
        Return false;
    }
    else if(document.channelForm.famName.value == “”) {
        alert(“Please provide your Family name.”);
        Return false;
    }
    else if(document.channelForm.firName.value == “”) {
        alert(“Please provide your First name.”);
        Return false;
    }
    else if(document.channelForm.email.value == “”) {
        alert(“Please provide your valid Email.”);
        Return false;
    }
    else if(document.channelForm.address.value == “”) {
        alert(“Please provide your Address.”);
        Return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("Everything is ok. Dont panic!") 
        Return true;
    }   
}
```

I have tested this button using an alert that say "working" so it definitely is linked to the code but when i try to use an if statement even if the condition is met it will not run the statement. Any help you more experienced fellows can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you're returning false if the field is blank, you don't actually need to nest the IF statements. It would be cleaner looking and easier to read if you separate them out

Comment: What's with the "smart quotes" `“”`? Not really an answer, just a guess, but swap those for regular quotes and see what happens. Also, lowercase `returns`.

Comment: @DBS What do you mean by seperate them out? Use seperate functions? And takendarkk yeah i just changed the quotes didn't notice them before (didn't fix the problems but thanks for the catch). Me and my brother prank each other and he knows ive started trying to code so i guess he though me wracking my brains over why stuff wasnt working cause of speech marks would be funny. I'll have to get him back haha

Comment: What I mean is you can effectively just cut out all of the "else" and it will work the same way. It won't affect the running of your code, it will just make the layout cleaner (In my opinion)

Comment: A simplified example: `if(x){return false}else{ alert ("Popup!") };` Could be cut down to `if(x){return false}; alert ("Popup!");` (In this case it doesn't make sense to cut it down as it's already very simple, but it would when you have multiple nested if statements like you have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Replace “” by ".
2. Replace `Return` by `return` **without uppercase**.
3. <s>*Change your text editor.*</s>

**Valid function :**

```js
function validateAndEmail() {
    var form = document.channelForm;
  console.log(form);
    if (form.chanName.value == "") {
        document.write("Please provide your channel name.");
        return false;
    } else if (form.chanURL.value == "") {
        document.write("Please provide your channel URL.");
        return false;
    } else if (form.famName.value == "") {
        document.write("Please provide your Family name.");
        return false;
    } else if (form.firName.value == "") {
        document.write("Please provide your First name.");
        return false;
    } else if (form.email.value == "") {
        document.write("Please provide your valid Email.");
        return false;
    } else if (form.address.value == "") {
        document.write("Please provide your Address.");
        return false;
    } else {
        document.write("Everything is ok. Dont panic!")
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="channelForm" onsubmit="validateAndEmail()">
  <input name="chanName"><br>
  <input name="chanURL"><br>
  <input name="famName"><br>
  <input name="firName"><br>
  <input name="email"><br>
  <input name="address"><br>
  
  
  <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
  
  
</form>
```

Comment: Did you test this? I put both of those suggestions in a comment instead of an answer because I hadn't tested.

Comment: it doesnt seem to work. Would you like to see all my code?

Comment: @jaymiddleton I add html example.

Comment: Even running your example. None of the javascript alerts will display

Comment: @jaymiddleton Because if you use Chrome, you have protection in jsfiddle  sandbox : "Ignored call to 'alert()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set." I replace alert by document write.

Comment: Ah whatever happened it now appears to work. Thankyou very much for the help!